# Create a syntax tree with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-trees

Is is possible to create this tree with LaTeX ?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {E}
      child {  node {F}   }

      child {  node {+}}

      child {  node {T}

      child {  node {T}
      child{node{F}

      child{node{8}} }}

      child { node {*} }

      child { node {F}

      child{node{2}}}};





\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**I managed to create the tree but I lack the attributes for example{Fv: = 2}**
[image]

Comment: There are *plenty* of tree examples on the site, (just clicking on the [tag:tikz-trees] or [tag:tikz-qtree] tags will show you lots of examples.) This one isn't particularly hard. I would recommend that you construct an example of what you have tried and then ask a more specific question based on that (for example how to align the annotations given a particular tree.)

Answer (score 6):

Adapting Gonzalo's answer to the `tikz-qtree` package we can achieve a similar result.  Note that strictly speaking you don't need to assign `\node`s to nodes which you are not referring to with other TikZ commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.\node(a) {E}; 
          [.\node (b) {F}; ] 
          [.\node (c) {+}; ] 
          [.\node (d) {T};
            [.\node (e) {T}; 
              [.\node (f) {F}; [.\node (g) {8}; ]]]
            [.\node (h) {*}; ]
            [.\node (i) {F};
              [.\node (j) {2}; ]
            ]
          ]
      ]
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
\node[right=of a] (na) {\{E.v${}\coloneqq{}$+T.v\}};
\node[right=of d] (nd) {\{T.v${}\coloneqq{}$F.v$^{*}$T.v\}};
\node[right=of i] (ni) {\{F.v${}\coloneqq{}$2\}};
\node[left=of b] (nb) {\{F.v${}\coloneqq{}$5\}};
\node[left=of e] (ne) {\{T.v${}\coloneqq{}$F.v\}};
\node[left=of f] (nf) {\{F.v${}\coloneqq{}$8\}};
\foreach \i in {a,b,d,e,f,i}
  \draw[dotted] (\i) -- (n\i);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I knew you were going to give the qtree version ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can name the nodes and then use these names to place the annotations using other `\node`s and the `positioning` library (I wasn't sure if the annotations should be in text or math mode, but you can easily change that); a simple `\foreach` loop allows to draw the dotted lines:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {E}
child {node (b) {F}
}
child {node (c) {+}
}
child {node (d) {T}
child {node (e) {T} 
  child {node (f) {F}  child {node  (g) {8}} }  
  }
child {node  (h) {*}}
child {node  (i) {F} child {node  (j) {2}}}
};
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
\node[right=of a] (na) {\{E.v${}\coloneqq{}$+T.v\}};
\node[right=of d] (nd) {\{T.v${}\coloneqq{}$F.v$^{*}$T.v\}};
\node[right=of i] (ni) {\{F.v${}\coloneqq{}$2\}};
\node[left=of b] (nb) {\{F.v${}\coloneqq{}$5\}};
\node[left=of e] (ne) {\{T.v${}\coloneqq{}$F.v\}};
\node[left=of f] (nf) {\{F.v${}\coloneqq{}$8\}};
\foreach \i in {a,b,d,e,f,i}
  \draw[dotted] (\i) -- (n\i);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In comments, the annotations were requested to be red and for the tree to have a caption:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning}

\begin{document}
An example of a cross-reference to Figure~\ref{fig:tree}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {E}
child {node (b) {F}
}
child {node (c) {+}
}
child {node (d) {T}
child {node (e) {T} 
  child {node (f) {F}  child {node  (g) {8}} }  
  }
child {node  (h) {*}}
child {node  (i) {F} child {node  (j) {2}}}
};
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={font=\footnotesize,color=red}]
\node[right=of a] (na) {\{E.v${}\coloneqq{}$+T.v\}};
\node[right=of d] (nd) {\{T.v${}\coloneqq{}$F.v$^{*}$T.v\}};
\node[right=of i] (ni) {\{F.v${}\coloneqq{}$2\}};
\node[left=of b] (nb) {\{F.v${}\coloneqq{}$5\}};
\node[left=of e] (ne) {\{T.v${}\coloneqq{}$F.v\}};
\node[left=of f] (nf) {\{F.v${}\coloneqq{}$8\}};
\foreach \i in {a,b,d,e,f,i}
  \draw[dotted] (\i) -- (n\i);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A syntactic tree}
\label{fig:tree}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ,how can I change the color attributes ? For example {F.v:=8} //red

Comment: @user29570 Colour attributes of what?  For nodes  you can add `[color=<colour>]` or create a style for a coloured node or all nodes. If you want to colour the branches, that's a bit more involved.

Comment: I want to change the color of the attributes :{E.v:=+T.v} ,{F.v:=5} ...

Comment: In the `every node/.style` definition you can add `,color=red` which will make those nodes red.  If you want the braces to be black, then it would make sense to create a macro to format the attributes so that you have the colour just inside. E.g. `\newcommand{\attr}[1]{\{{\color{\attrcolor}#1}\}}` and then use `\attr{E.v${}\coloneqq{}$+T.v}`, for example. This macro assumes an `\attrcolor` which you define with `\newcommand{\attrcolor}{red}`.

Comment: Thank you,how to assign a title for this tree?

Comment: @user29570 what exactly do you mean with a title? Do you mean a caption as in "Figure 2: a representation of..."? If this is so, the wrap the entire `tikzpicture` inside a `figure` environment and use the standard `\caption` command. If you don't know how to do that, or if you meant other kind of title, let me know to help you.

Comment: yes like "Figure2:representation of ..." ,but I don't know how to do it :3

Comment: @user29570 No problem. Please see my updated answer. Also, don't forget to accept (different from upvote) the answer that you consider best solved your problem. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: Hi,How to increase the distance between nodes ?